# What do we call "down" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

"I have fallen down."

I thought adjective at first, but it isn't really an adjective right? Because it doesn't really modify me, it modifies how I fell? So it is modifying the verb.

Comment: If it modifies  a verb it is an .......

Comment: I guess it's an Adverb. Thanks Edwin